# Accessing flask context outside the main class

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error

I'm new to python, therefore I believe solution might be quick one. I've spent hours, but couldn't make it work.

I need to access app outside main class.
Package structure below:

```
app/
   app.py
   another_class.py
```

In app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

In another_class.py:

```
from flask import current_app as app

app.config['test_key']
```

Of course I receive error

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

I've tried running it in block of

```
with app.app_context:
```

but it didn't seem to work.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here.

> I need to access app outside main class

And you are trying to solve it the wrong way. `current_app` is useful to use features that are originally used externally. Typically, a use case would be to simulate routes, but offline.

What you want to do, is have a file that will "manage" your application, such as `manage.py` for instance. Then, another file `app.py` that will contain the configuration of your application.

In your `manage.py` file, you will `import app` in order to run it. And if you then need to access to your `app` object, you can `import app` from your another file. Basically, the `app` object you're instantiating in the `app.py` acts like a pointer, and the other files importing the app will also be affected by the change you make in another file to this object `app`.

Your tree should look like this.

```
your_api/
    app.py # Instantiate the app object.
    manage.py # Import the app.py package to run it.
    another_file.py # If this file imports app.py and modifies the app object
                    # inside, the changes will also affect the object imported by manage.py.
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. All I do is to get value from `config` in `another_file.py`. That's why I'm referencing `app`. Is there more simplified way of doing it?

Comment: @zeromaro don't you find my solution pretty simple already ? ;) I think this is the best and simplest way to my knowledge yes.

Comment: As I'm new to Python, it doesn't look that easy haha. Could you help me on that?

Now it looks like this:
`app.py`
`
from flask import Flask
from .manage import test_method

app = Flask(__name__)

test_method()
`


`manage.py`
`
import app

def test_method():
    print(app.config['test_key'])
`

I receive
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`